# Message sent using WhatsApp business API but not delivered to recipients

Tags: whatsapp

I've setup a WhatsApp Business to test WhatsApp API for sending messages. I've followed the getting started guide, but when I send a test message from the main interface of WhatsApp API, the message is sent but is not received by the recipient, even though there is a template approved by Facebook

As shown in the pictures, when I press send message, the sending succeeds but the recipient receives nothing

update : i added a real number ( not using a facebook testing number ) also did not work

[image]